# Can I do a multi query on collections in Cassandra 2.1?

Tags: cassandra, cql

IN Cassandra 2.1, we can query on collections by creating a secondary index on the column.

```
cqlsh:play> select * from songs where tags contains 't1';

 id                                   | tags         | title

--------------------------------------+--------------+-------

 e99f8f30-d212-11e4-bc9e-5d1b1922b94d | {'t1', 't2'} | Song1
```

But I want to query on multiple values - like this:

```
select * from songs where tags contains 't1|t2';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Sort of, yes.  Should you do it?  No, not really.  Let me explain...

While Carlo is correct in that CQL does not support `OR`, this can be made to work with `AND`.  That is, you want to query on the presence of both tags, you can do this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM songs
  WHERE tags CONTAINS 't2' AND tags CONTAINS 't1' ALLOW FILTERING;

 id                                   | tags         | title
--------------------------------------+--------------+-------
 75e46eb2-292a-42d0-8330-510fb35c635b | {'t1', 't2'} | Song1

(1 rows)
```

While this *technically* works, it is a **TERRIBLE IDEA**

- Multi-key querying has been identified as an anti-pattern.  Using simultaneous, asynchronous queries is typically faster than using `IN` or `CONTAINS` to bring back rows for multiple keys.  DataStax has a section of the `SELECT` documentation titled [When Not To Use In](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectInNot) that you should read through.
- Secondary indexes do not perform well, and it would be only logical that secondary indexes on collections would perform even worse than their single-valued counterparts.  In fact the documentation has a whole section on [When Not To Use An Index](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html) that you should really read before using them.
- To make the `AND` operator work on the collection twice, `ALLOW FILTERING` is required.  `ALLOW FILTERING` essentially brings back every row (from every node) you have, and *then* filters the results.  If you have a large dataset and/or several nodes, you should **never** use a query that requires `ALLOW FILTERING` to complete.

The *right* way to do this, is to build an additional query table with `tag` as the partition key (and `id` as a clustering key for uniqueness).

```
CREATE TABLE songsByTag (
  tag text,
  title text,
  id uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY ((tag),id));
```

This will allow you to query songs by a particular tag, without requiring a secondary index.  And while that would allow you to then use `IN` (which is essentially an `OR`), multiple, asynchronous queries for each key (tag) would still be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: there is no support for `OR` operator in Cassandra.

Cheers,
Carlo