# Data modelling for a query requiring multiple tags

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I'm having some trouble figuring out an appropriate way to model out a query that requires multiple matching tags.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show_by_type (show_id UUID, tags frozen<set<VARCHAR>>, show_type VARCHAR

PRIMARY KEY(show_type, tags, show_id));
```

If a movie has the following tags [Horror, Thriller, English] (just an example)
I'd need to make reads matching both Horror and English for example and not checking for Thriller.

```
SELECT * FROM show_by_type where show_type = 'movie' AND tags CONTAINS 'Horror' AND tags CONTAINS 'English';
```

I've done a bit of research trying to figure out what the proper way of modelling out data would be for this, but I can't figure out an approach that won't require ALLOW FILTERING. There's already a secondary index on this column so just running a single CONTAINS works.

[Can I do a multi query on collections in Cassandra 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277096/can-i-do-a-multi-query-on-collections-in-cassandra-2-1)

I took a look at the above link, but that would only work if I needed to query for one tag at a time.

Any ideas on how I could change my data model to allow for matching multiple values in a set in queries?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are correct in saying that you can only select multiple values from the set by adding ALLOW FILTERING so

```
SELECT * FROM show_by_type where show_type = 'movie'
 AND tags CONTAINS 'Horror' AND tags CONTAINS 'English'
 ALLOW FILTERING;
```

The addition of a secondary index on a set-type column probably doesn't work as you intended, because queries against a secondary index are limited to equality '=' and probably cannot index a dynamic column such as a set, with varying membership.

To directly answer your last question, it is difficult to see how you can precisely query what you need, whilst they are contained in a set. You would have to consider adding additional structured columns like 'language','primary_genre' etc and use the set for additional tags that only occur in a subset of the entire set of records.